# Alternatives to minimum spanning tree and neighborhood graphs

Tags: graph-theory

I am looking to represent data drawn from a high-dimensional manifold with a weighted graph. The shortest path distances in the graph are meant to approximate geodesic distance.

I've tried both minimum spanning trees and neighborhood graphs, but they're not exactly what I'm looking for.

Minimum spanning trees are nice because shortest paths are unique, and thus, very easy to compute. They are also relatively quick to construct. My issue is that minimum spanning trees are maybe too sparse, leading to greedy paths, i.e. paths that are constructed by concatenating the shortest edges. These paths tend to be windy and inefficient. I also do not require my graph to be a tree.

Neighborhood graphs have been used in algorithms like IsoMap (doesn't work well in high dimension). The issue is that neighborhood graphs do not guarantee connectedness, which I need (so that I have all pairwise path distances). If I choose a neighborhood size large enough to ensure connectedness, then the graph becomes too complex and the distances are basically Euclidean.

I suppose I am looking for something in between minimum spanning trees and neighborhood graphs -- one that contains slightly more edges than a spanning tree and guarantees connectedness. Any suggestions?

Comment: $k$-nearest neighbor graph?

Answer (score 1):

If it is of your interest that the total weight of all edges in the graph is not too large, while the paths are efficient, a suggestion would be a "shallow-light tree". This is a tree that simultaneously approximates a minimum spanning tree and a shortest-path tree. A very basic approximation algorithm is given by Awerbuch et al. .

Based on the idea of the neighborhood graph, a way to achieve connectedness while  not adding too many edges could be t0 apply the algorithm iteratively: Compute the neighborhood graph, contract the connected components and compute a neighborhood graph in the resulting graph with a different distance threshold (or just add a shortest path between each two components) until everything is connected.

Comment: These are two very interesting ideas. Thank you!